# Toggle Switch on Navbar

Tags: toggle

Is it good to add a toggle switch on a navbar. I need to switch between the 2 contents in a page by a toggle-switch. If not suggest me a good way to toggle the content

Comment: It would be nice if you expanded your question and explain why you don't use e.g. two links instead of the toggle-switch. Maybe give an example of a specific use case for your toggle-switch.

Comment: I used tabs for my purpose

Comment: Google Inbox is an example of implementing page change with a toggle switch, however I'm not a big fan of it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a toggle switch, a tabbed navigation might be more suitable. consider the example of navigation clothes, the tab on top would separate men and womens clothes.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain it a bit more? maybe a screenshot would help.

However, I would not suggest to use a toggle on the main navigation to switch content. The basic idea of a toggle button is to show enable/disable or rather on/off states. So this might confuse your users. Why don't you use 2 links instead? You could make them prominent by using a primary colour which goes with your branding.